# Convert .wav file to binary and then back to .wav?

Tags: java, audio, binary, wave

I'm doing a project in java which requires me to encrypt a wave file. So, is there a straight forward process to convert a wave file into binary and back? I'll be applying an encryption algorithm on the binary data.

Comment: I mean bits....series of 1's and 0's

Comment: @Uday: Yes, I realise that!  What I mean is, what do you want that binary to represent?  A file is already a series of 1s and 0s.  Why can't you just read the file into a `byte[]`?  Why does it matter that it's specifically a .wav file?

Comment: Reading a binary file into a char array is probably a very stupid thing to do.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Yes, my mistake.  I meant `byte` array...

Comment: You'll find most things in a computer are binary already. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
File file = new File("music.wav");
byte[] data = new byte[file.length()];
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
in.read(data);
in.close();

//encrypt data

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

Of course assuming it's still a valid wav file after you play around with the data.

Comment: There is no guarantee that in.read(data) will read all of the file. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[]) states that it will read _up to_ b.length bytes.

Comment: Yes, but that assumes the array isn't big enough, which it is. File.length() is the length of a file. However, if you want to be careful you could compare the value returned by read to the size of the file to be sure.

Comment: @Trey - no, it has nothing to do with the size of the array.  it has to do with the stream implementation.  you should _never_ assume that `read()` will fill your array.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked!! :) I was unnecessarily meddling with AudioInputStream until now!

Comment: Ummm I'm getting the original file back now...of course i didnt apply any encryption as of yet, I just converted the bytes to bits and then back to bytes and then back to wave file..so now do I need to bother about read() not reading the entire file??

Comment: @Uday Kanth - Yes, you should be concerned about read() not reading the complete file. It will probably work for small files, might work for larger files but it is not guaranteed. You can either read in a loop or use something like http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.3.2/index.html IOUtils.

Comment: Would using a ByteArrayOutputStream help?

Comment: @Paul how do I import those packages into my program?

Answer (score 4):

Most languages have utilities to read and write files in binary mode. If you happen to be on a Linux system, it's the same as character mode. In any case, it's not a matter of "converting" to binary, just a different method of reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Java Wav IO](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the plugin : JLayer